# PHP: Getting warning if $_GET is empty

Tags: php, arrays, get

I get the array data like this:

```
$tags = $_GET['item']['tags'];  

if ($tags){
    foreach ($tags as $tag){
```

As the tags data is sent from an input field, which can be empty as well. So in case if `$tags` doesn't get any data, i get the following notice:

```
Message: Undefined index: item
```

How can I avoid this notice?

if i try this:

```
$tags = isset($_GET['item']['tags']);
```

Then if `$tags` does not get any data, it does not show any warning, but if it gets any data then i get following warning:

```
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

How can I do it so that if `$tags` get any data then go to `foreach` loop, otherwise don't give any notice that it didnt get any data.

Thanks.

Comment: What does `var_dump($tags)` give you when it *it gets any data*? `Array(...)` or `String "..."`?

Comment: var_dump returns array: `array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "abc" [1]=> string(3) "def" [2]=> string(3) "ghi" }`

Comment: Ah... `$tags = isset(...)` means that `$tags` becomes either `true` or `false` which you cannot pass onto `foreach`. Eddie's answer answers what you need to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
$tags = isset($_GET['item']['tags']) ? $_GET['item']['tags'] :'';
```

Comment: He will still need to check if *$tags* is not empty before the loop.

Comment: i recognize that notation but don't know it.  can you explain it?

Comment: thanks @Eddie. that's a succinct explanation with easy examples.

Comment: @Eddie I suggest that instead of assigning `''`, the script assigns `array()`.  That way, there's no need to check for an empty string, the `foreach` loop will simply run zero times.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if( !is_null( $_GET["item"]["tags"] ) )
{
    $tags = $_GET["item"]["tags"];
    foreach($tags as $tag)
    {
        //do stuff here
    }
}
```

Also, you said in your question that you are posting the data, but you use $_GET to retrieve your variables.  This could be a problem too.

Comment: This is not correct, as $_GET["item"] part will return null and null["tags"] is exactly what brings up the warning.

Comment: does changing it to !is_null($_GET["item"]["tags"]) solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you just want to turn off error display, that's easy by modifying php.ini to not show the errors...

Then when I am debugging, I use this to ensure that I can see those errors...

```
$debug = 1;
if($debug){
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
}
```

Anytime your running a foreach loop, you'll want to run a count on the array

```
$array = array();
if(count($array) > 0){
    foreach($array as $key=>$value){
         //Stuff here...
    }
}
```

in your case, chage it to this:

```
$tags = $_GET['item']['tags'];  

//TAGS MUST BE AN OBJECT OR AN ARRAY....

if (count($tags) > 0){
    foreach($tags as $tag){
       //....Code here.
    }
}
```